# Excessive threads created by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I usually run programs through Eclipse that run hundreds/thousands of threads and I am attempting to do some benchmarking today. I noticed there were somewhere around 100 threads still active after doing some tests so I decided to restart Eclipse, assuming the threads were left over from one of my programs that didn't shut down properly or something.  However, when I restart Eclipse, it has over 100 threads (when viewed with htop on Centos OS 7), so it seems like these threads are related to Eclipse and not my programs. Is this normal?  That seems like a very large number of threads to be sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: Are the threads actively running?  Are they marked with a "Z"?  Are they otherwise occupying system resources?

Comment: They aren't taking any CPU time and their memory usage is identical for all of them, so I assume it's actually the usage of the parent thread. Marked in what column? In the S column they are marked with S

Comment: If that's the case then that indicates that those threads are sleeping and aren't occupying CPU cycles.  Doesn't seem like it's much of an issue unless you're actively running into a thread limit in userspace.

Comment: You are probably right, but it seems pretty ridiculous for Eclipse to be spawning 100 seemingly useless threads.

Comment: Were you going to look at their names and stacks, or is writing them off as useless good enough for you?

Comment: They all have the same name (at least the portion that is on the screen--they are so long they go off the screen and I don't know how to capture the rest). I'm not sure what you mean by stacks in this context.